# Kong Installation issues on RHEL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, kong

I am trying to install Kong on a RHEL machine but getting an error when I run kong migration command. "$ kong migrations up -c /etc/kong/kong.conf"

```
2018/01/22 14:56:28 [verbose] running datastore migrations
Error:
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:34: [cassandra error] could not find coordinator: all hosts tried for query failed. 10.29.169.158: host seems unhealthy, considering it down (connection refused)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:34: in function 'cmd_exec'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:87: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/init.lua:44>
        /usr/local/bin/kong:7: in function 'file_gen'
        init_worker_by_lua:46: in function <init_worker_by_lua:44>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        init_worker_by_lua:53: in function <init_worker_by_lua:51>
```

I have installed Cassandra 3.11.1 and have created a keyspace and role named 'kong'. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem, consider adding it _as an answer_, instead of editing your question to add it.

Comment: done! - new to the community, getting used to the features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue got resolved after adding the Cassandra RPC address at /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yml and created a working directory for kong(at /usr/local/bin/kong). Granted permission to kong user on all keyspaces.